# Insert and update simultaneously

Tags: sql, oracle

To insert an identical row to a table I use

```
Insert into table (select * from table where columnA = 'a' and columnB = 'b')
```

Am I able to insert and change columnB = 'c' in one sql?

Comment: @jonathan: Have you tried running this ?

Comment: My table have 60 column. only 1 column need to change to different value.

Comment: @Gaurav Soni yes I have run it. It works but I don't know how to insert and update to the new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just specify the value in the select:

```
insert into table (ColumnA, ColumnB)
select ColumnA, 'c'
from table
where columnA = 'a' and columnB = 'b'
```

(If you have more columns, just add them in the column list and the select just like ColumnA.)

Comment: I have 60 columns do I have to include all in the list?

Comment: @JonathanChan Yes, you do. Consider using a select against [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2656.htm) to build the query (or at least the column list) for you. An alternative approach is to update the table after the insert, and only commit after that (but I suspect you already know that).